# zurb: Icons within buttons

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Basically I am trying to add an icon (I have chosen to use foundations icon fonts for ease) to a button.

I've had a look through the forums and I can find an answer to the above when referring to simple/standard buttons, however I want to achieve this within a form.

I am basically building a checkout page and want to add a paypal logo to the final 'checkout' button.

This was my initial thought:

```
<input class="button checkout-button" type="submit" name="checkout" value="<i class="fi-paypal"></i>Checkout">
```

However this doesn't work - I assume this is because the value is taking the ( " ) before the icon class to be the closing quote and simply adding the remaining code on as text afterwards to create some pretty unattractive results.

Is there a way around this I am overlooking, or an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
<button class="button checkout-button" type="submit" name="checkout" ><i class="fi-paypal">       </i>Checkout</button>
```